# Google+ sign in button in android . These are my java file and error log

Tags: pointers, exception, null

**JAVA:**

```
    package com.example.api_test;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import  com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
    import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements       OnClickListener,ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

    Button bSignIn;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN=1;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private boolean mIntentInProgress, mSignInClicked;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();

            bSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
            bSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button
            && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
          }
        }


    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
          if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution() && mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            try {
              mIntentInProgress = true;
              startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                  RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
              mIntentInProgress = false;
              mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
          }
        }





    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}





    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()){
            try{
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                startIntentSenderForResult(result.getResolution().getIntentSender(), RC_SIGN_IN ,null ,0 ,0 , 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e){
                mIntentInProgress =false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

        if (mSignInClicked){
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
      mSignInClicked = false;
      Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent){
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK){
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }
            mIntentInProgress = false ;

        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        }
    }


}
```

**Error log:**

```
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888): Process: com.example.api_test, PID: 888
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at com.example.api_test.MainActivity.resolveSignInError(MainActivity.java:61)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at com.example.api_test.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:50)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-26 18:39:18.940: E/AndroidRuntime(888):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and when do you get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have not initialized your variable `MConnectionResult` to anything, and on line 61 you are getting a NullPointer Exception.